# I'm Doing push notification in android using php as a back end.how to retrive My Sql database values into android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm doing a push notification project In my android first layout is search.There i want get complaint id from My sql database... Means i already created one table complaint details it have the complaint id.actually my project is customer will call to the customer care executive for registering complaint while this time he/she will ask complaint id.. In search field i enter that id and checks whether it is existing or not.. I'm checking this value in MySql database..M y question is  how to get that value from there

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Call a server side script from your android application using **HttpPost**,

**Step 2:** Your server side script will execute some **sql search query** and return back data to your appplication in **JSON/XML** formet.

**Note:** dont forget send all **needful data** for your sql query from your app to server by httppost